# Count the amount of individual characters (vowels) within a string in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I've just started programming in C, and I have to create a program that counts how many vowels a string has. So far I have this:

```
int a; 
int len = strlen(text)-1
for(a=0;a==len;++a){
    if(text[a]=='a'){
        ++vocals;}
```

I'm clueless on what's wrong, because it will always print 0. I understand my code as:

- starting on the first char until the last one before \0,
- compare them to 'a', and if they do equal, add one to the counter.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `a==len;` is wrong. The condition must be a condition to continue the loop.

Comment: `a != len`. It's a continuation condition, not a termination condition.

Comment: OT: `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: @Pelput  'a' is not the only vowel.:)

Answer (score 0):

Check your tutorials or textbook on the syntax and semantics of the for loop.

It requires a continuation condition, i.e. "loop as long as this is true".

So in your code you should change to:

```
for(a=0; a<len; ++a)
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
for(a=0;a==len;++a)
```

to

```
for(a=0;a<=len;++a)
```

first iteration `a` is not equal to `len` so it will never enter the loop. you want to iterate over this for loop as long as `a` is lesser of eual to `len`, second statement does precisely that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* text = "this is a test";
    int i, vocals;
    int len = strlen(text);
    for(i=0;i<len;++i){
        if(text[i]=='a'||text[i]=='e'||text[i]=='i'||text[i]=='o'||text[i]=='u')
            ++vocals;
    }
    printf("%d\n", vocals);
}
```

This is a working little program.
Let's look at the main together:

- First we declare a char arrays, since you omitted that part i assume your string is correctly formed.
- The for loop continues till i becames equal to len. It's a good programming practice to use `<` or `>` instead of `!=` or `==` to increment the strength of the code. Anyway since it's a small program you can even use `!=` which means "Execute the for loop till `i` becames equal to `len`"
- In the if statement we are just checking if the current character is equal to 'a' **or** 'e' **or** 'i' **or** 'o' **or** 'u'. As you may now guess `||` operator means `or`.

---

EDIT:

There are a lot of more efficient (and complex) way to do this. For example using [Regular Expression](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espressione_regolare). If you're interested there are a lot of good tutorial online, for example [this](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/2844_Learning-about-Regular-Expressions-in-C-through-examples.html)

Comment: Thank you! You made it super clear now! To use the other vocals i tried `if(text[a]=='a' || 'b')` and so on. Now it does make sense.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this aswer usefull acept the answer clicking on the left check icon.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet

```
int a; 
int len = strlen(text)-1
for(a=0;a==len;++a){
    if(text[a]=='a'){
        ++vocals;}
```

does not make great sense.

For example the character `'a'` is not the only vowel, the condition `a == len` is evaluated to true only when the string contains just one character.

You can write a separate function that counts vowels in a string.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t count_vowels( const char *s )
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    size_t count = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( strchr( vowels, tolower( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) )
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello Pelput";

    printf( "There are %zu vowels in the string\n\"%s\"\n",
        count_vowels( s ), s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
There are 4 vowels in the string
"Hello Pelput"
```